# Letters and Numbers

Tags: mathematics

Every letter is a different value from 1-26

1. A x A = L + G
2. C x C = U
3. J x H = P + R
4. W - K = N
5. G + L = E + Z
6. S + J = P - Y
7. E x C = Z x B
8. D + U = Z + E
9. G x F = D + U
10. O + X = V
11. S x K = Z + E
12. K x R = M
13. D + U = R + P
14. Q is higher than T
15. O is higher than I

Can you work out their values?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Puzzling. Is this your own puzzle? If not, we need to have [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for puzzles that you didn't create; this helps prevent plagiarism on our site. Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: Hi, I wrote it, sorry i didnt know i have to mention that

Comment: @LizardofOz you don't have to mention that it is your own puzzle; if it is not yours you have to provide proper attribution.

Comment: It is still safer to mention it is one's own puzzle if it looks like it could have been taken from somewhere else, or it might get closed.

Comment: A and C can only be 3, 4 or 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key to this puzzle is that

> Lines 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11 and 13 all have the same value: a square with at least 7 divisors greater than 1. These are A,F,G,H,J,K and S. The only possible value for this is square is 36, so we have A = 6 and the other six are 2, 3, 4, 9, 12, and 18.

We can proceed with:

> C x C = U must be 5 x 5 = 25, as C is not a factor of 36.
>  U + D = 36 gives us D = 11.
>  F x G = G + L = 36, and this can only be 3 x 12 = 12 + 24.
>  R + P = 36 gives R > 9 and K x R = M gives us K = 2
>  S x K = 36 gives us S = 18
>  E x C = Z x B with Z + E = 36 gives us 36 / E = (5 + B) / B.
>  Trial and error finds E = 21 and B = 7

Further trial and error and a process of elimination complete the solution:

> ```
>  A =  6  |  N = 17
>  B =  7  |  O = 14
>  C =  5  |  P = 23
>  D = 11  |  Q = 20
>  E = 21  |  R = 13
>  F =  3  |  S = 18
>  G = 12  |  T = 16
>  H =  9  |  U = 25
>  I = 10  |  V = 22
>  J =  4  |  W = 19
>  K =  2  |  X =  8
>  L = 24  |  Y =  1
>  M = 26  |  Z = 15
> ```

Comment: perfectly done, nice job

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a correct answer got posted while I was working on this, but the following identifies all the values without trial and error:

> First observe that there are lots of common elements in (1), (3), (5), (8), (9), (11) and (13).
>  Combining them we have A*A = G*F = S*K = J*H = L+G = E+Z = D+U = R+P.
>  The sums must all be between 3 and 51, so we need a square between 4 and 49 that can be factored four different ways.
>  The only possibility is 36 = 6*6 = 4*9 = 3*12 = 2*18.
>  So A = 6.
>
>  All the letters in the sums must be at least 10, but cannot be 18, and as G appears in both a sum and a product we know G = 12.
>  And that means F = 3 and L = 24.

> Now look at (12): K x R = M
>  We know R >= 10 from the sums to 36, so K <= 2. But K=1 gives R=M.
>  So K = 2.
>  From the sums to 36, we know R >= 10, so 10 <= R <= 13, and 20 <= M <= 26.
>  And from the products to 36, we have S = 18, leaving J and H as 4 and 9 (but we don't know which way round yet).

> Now look at (6): S + J = P - Y
>  We know S = 18, and J = 4 or 9.
>  But the difference can be at most 25, so J = 4 .
>
>  So we have 22 = P - Y.
>  So Y <= 4, and the only free option is Y = 1.
>  Leaving P = 23.
>
>  And from the sums and products to 36, that means R = 13 and H = 9.
>  And from (12), M = 26.

> Now look at (2): C x C = U.
>  The square gives us 2 <= C <= 5, and the only remaining option is C = 5.
>  So U = 25.
>  And from the sums to 36, that means D = 11.

> Now look at (7) - E x C = Z x B
>  We know C = 5, so Z*B must be a multiple of 5.
>  We also know E and Z sum to 36, and with several values taken, both must be between 14 and 22.
>
>  Rearranging we have E/Z = B/5.
>  With all lower values taken, we know B >= 7, and that also means E > Z.
>
>  If B >= 10 we would have E/Z >= 2, which is impossible given the possible values.
>  So 7 <= B <= 9
>
>  And that means Z must be a multiple of 5, and the only possibility is Z = 15.
>  So E = 21.
>  And B = 7.

> Now look at (10): O + X = V
>  With most values taken, there is only one possibility here: 8 + 14 = 22.
>  So V = 22.
>  And O,X are 8,14 in some order.
>
>  Looking at (15): O is higher than I
>  O cannot be 8, as there are no lower values free for I.
>  So O = 14 and X = 8.
>  And I = 10 (The only lower value available.)

> Now look at (4): W - 2 = N
>  There is only one option among the remaining values: 19 - 2 = 17.
>  So W = 19 and N = 17
>
>  And finally (14): Q is higher than T makes Q = 20 and T = 16

> ```
> 1   Y
> 2   K
> 3   F
> 4   J
> 5   C
> 6   A
> 7   B
> 8   X
> 9   H
> 10  I
> 11  D
> 12  G
> 13  R
> 14  O
> 15  Z
> 16  T
> 17  N
> 18  S
> 19  W
> 20  Q
> 21  E
> 22  V
> 23  P
> 24  L
> 25  U
> 26  M
> ```